# If $p , q , r , s$ belongs to set of real numbers then equation $(x^2+px+3q)(-x^2+rx+q)(-x^2+sx-2q) = 0$: what type of roots does it have?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is an objective type question 
its answers are :

A - $6$ real roots

B - at least $2$ real roots

C - $2$ real and $4$ imaginary roots

D - $4$ real and $2$ imaginary roots

there could be multiple choices

Comment: Please format the question better. It's not a good idea to write long equations in the title. Also, please use proper line breaks and MathJax.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please write your question in the body and not in the title

Comment: Any own thoughts about the problem?

Comment: At least 2 real roots (B) is certainly correct - either by looking at the middle factor or by seeing all other choices contain it.  Is this supposed to have multiple correct choices?

Comment: @Macavity it isn't - choice B's meaning is that there are $2$, $4$, or $6$ real roots - *but we can't tell how many*

Comment: @RhysHughes At least $2$ real roots is obviously correct. Of course it doesn’t tell exactly how many, or which those roots are etc but that’s irrelevant. I see you have posted a solution agreeing with my comment above.

Comment: @Macavity, when questions like this are asked, generally option $B$ *would not* be accepted if it was possible to show exactly how many real/complex roots the equation has. So IF it were correct that the equation had, say, six real roots for all $p,q,r,s$, then $A$ would be considered correct, and $B$ would be considered incorrect.

Comment: @RhysHughes You are contradicting your answer below.  In any case, the truth value of one statement does not depend on whether some other statement is "more specifically true".  Independently and invariably, option B is correct.

Comment: In this question, solely because we can't tell how many roots are real, $B$ is correct. If we could tell, $B$ would be an incorrect choice

Answer (score 1):

We have no information regarding positivity, negativity or relative magnitudes, so it's impossible to determine how the roots will come.

A simple performance of the quadratic formula on each bracket shows us the three discriminants we are after.
$$p^2-12q$$$$r^2+4q$$$$s^2-8q$$
whether these three are $<0$, or $>0$ is what we need to find.

The second one is only negative for negative $q$, in this case  the other two are positive. This implies $4$ real roots, and thereby two complex. However, should $p^2<12q$ and $s^2<8q$, with $q>0$, then the second is positive but the other two are negative: four complex solutions and two reals. Moreover, if $p^2>12q$ and $s^2>8q$, with $q>0$, all three discriminants are positive and so we have six real solutions.

So the correct answer is $(B)$ there are at least two real solutions.